# How to perform arithmetic operations on input through EditText which are created programmatically?

Tags: java, android

I have  created  EditText textView Buttons using for loops in  MainActivity.Java  not in activity_main.Xml.
I want to do arithmetic calculations on the inputted numbe rthrough EditText.

Here is my code:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private static final int MY_BUTTON = 9000;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(layout.activity_main);

   final LinearLayout my_root = (LinearLayout)findViewById(id.Root);

    for(int i =1;i<=5;i++){


        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams ParamLayout =
                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        ParamLayout.gravity=Gravity.CENTER;

        layout.setLayoutParams(ParamLayout);

        TextView tvi = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
        tvi.setText("Sub " + String.valueOf(i));
        tvi.setId(i);
        tvi.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tvi.setTextSize(24);
        tvi.setPadding(0,0,5,3);
        tvi.setMinWidth(300);
        tvi.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD),Typeface.ITALIC);



        layout.addView(tvi,0);

        EditText etCrediti = new EditText(this);
        etCrediti.setHint("Credit ");
        etCrediti.setMinWidth(300);
        etCrediti.setId(50+i);
        etCrediti.setMinLines(1);
        etCrediti.setMaxLines(1);
        layout.addView(etCrediti);

        EditText etPointsi = new EditText(this);
        etPointsi.setText(" ");
        etPointsi.setMinWidth(300);
        etPointsi.setId(100+i);
        etPointsi.setMinLines(1);
        etPointsi.setMaxLines(1);
        layout.addView(etPointsi);

        my_root.addView(layout);


    }

    Button btn = new Button(this);
    btn.setText("Submit");
    btn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
  // b.setId(MY_BUTTON);
    //btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    btn.setTextSize(24);
    btn.setWidth(300);
    btn.setId(MY_BUTTON);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    my_root.addView(btn);





}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We are a question-and-answer site, not a coders-for-hire service. Please explain what you have tried so far and why it hasn't worked.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Why are you putting editText inside a **FOR** loop?

Comment: Sir i want to perform arithmetic operation e.g if I want to add five numbers ,five editbox should open .I will enter the five numbers which I want to add  and should give the results...

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you wanted to do is a calculator...
You must have for this two editTexts and a button.
You should also have another TextView for the result.
You need to set the button on click to the function that calculate.

In your on create set b1 and b2 to the views editText.
b1= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

Then to get the text value:
int n1= Integer.pharseInt(b1.getText.toString());

Then just do the calc and set the result for the TextView text.
findViewById (R.id.textView1).setText(result);

I also add a link for tutorial below:

https://www.google.co.il/amp/www.androidauthority.com/build-a-calculator-app-721910/amp/

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with `EditText` in Android, I had to convert the number-string to different type that can be calculated with by Java.

When you expect a 'double' you can use the following Java code-snippet:

```
EditText myNumericTextfield = ...
...
// fill value of myNumericTextfield
...
double valueOfMyNumericTextfield = 0.0;
try {
   valueOfMyNumericTextfield = Double.parseDouble(myNumericTextfield.toString());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
   System.err.println(e);
   throw new Exception(e);
}
...
```

You can also convert the string `myNumericTextfield` to an `int`, or `long`.